# REST API how to handle a particular case

Tags: rest, api

Let's say I have a REST API that handles the creation of a user

**POST domain/api/users**

And accept a list of parameters such as

- first_name
- last_name
- email
- password
- profile

I want the endpoint to be generic (it should be the same endpoint to create any type of user, not specific for each profile), but I also want to make sure that some of the clients that request a user creation have a limitation: they can only create users with a given profile.
Although imposing the profile type is a responsibility of the caller, I would love to perform a validation.

I don't like the idea of creating another endpoint (and then another... and then another..). Is there a standard way to handle a case like this?

---

I have read some of the replies below and probably some additional info is required in order to understand the question.
I am aware I can perform a validation based on the "caller", for example by having a ACL based security, but is this the "*correct*" way to handle this issue or is there a different (and widely adopted) solution?

Thanks

Comment: you can always pass the client profile and filter the request before passing to the user creation route, that the client profile has access to create the following user profile.

Comment: *I want the endpoint to be generic* Clarify it.

Comment: Why don't you send a JSON in the request payload?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin edited to specify the "generic" part

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar case where our API is being consumed by 8-10 clients internally in the company. And not all of them can create accounts with admin privilege. The way we are handling this is , we maintain a client access token for each of the client. As per the client access token, we let them create account with different privilege (admin, user, agent).

This client access token can be passed in the http header like internal-access-token = 64888hhihi7869jhdu. You can have something in your filter and as per that you can set the profile type as admin or agent or user.

Also this way even though client 1 sends the profile value as admin in the request body, still you can actually not let them create a user with that privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Any validation you want to do should be done before the request reaches to endpoint.

There are ways and tools for it but they all basically do the same thing as put a filter on the api, get the header from the request, verify the header data for valid client and proceed with it only when it's valid.

As for when you say generic, you need to clarify what you mean with it, you can create a generic request body to accommodate all the client specification. If the user needs to be created differently for different client, instead of having different API you may want to use factory design pattern inside the API.